# ggplot, geom_segment, mapping or setting of xend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently working on the code of "R graphics cookbook", Chapter 3, as provided by user "gaorongchao" on github:

A) code as given

```
install.packages(gcookbook)
library(gcookbook)
tophit <- tophitters2001[1:25, ]
nameorder <- tophit$name[order(tophit$lg, tophit$avg)]
tophit$name <- factor(tophit$name, levels=nameorder)

ggplot(tophit, aes(x=avg, y=name)) +
geom_segment(aes(yend=name), xend=0, colour="grey50") +
geom_point(aes(colour=lg), size=3) +
scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1", limits=c("NL","AL")) +
theme_bw() +
theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
      legend.position=c(1, 0.55),
      legend.justification=c(1, 0.5))
```

B) Then I tried a variation with

```
ggplot(tophit, aes(x=avg, y=name)) +
geom_segment(aes(xend=0, yend=name), colour="grey50") +
geom_point(aes(colour=lg), size=3) +
scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1", limits=c("NL","AL")) +
theme_bw() +
theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
      legend.position=c(1, 0.55),
      legend.justification=c(1, 0.5))
```

where xend is part of the aes mapping in geom_segment(). B) leads to another graphic with another scale, where xend=0 is explicitly part of the x-scale. Can somehow explain the systematic behind this difference of code A) and B)? xend being part of aes and being not. What is the difference? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is required to set aesthetic mappings to your data frame inside `aes()` - only inside `aes()` will `ggplot` know to look in your data frame form a column name.

Constants, like your `xend = 0`, or `color = "red"` if you wanted to color all points red, *can* be set inside `aes()`, but **it is generally preferred to set them outside of `aes()`**. For something like color, this will not automatically create a legend (you normally don't want a color legend if there is only one color). Similarly, in your example, you saw that putting `xend = 0` inside `aes()` make it "explicitly part of the scale".

Setting a constant *inside* `aes` is equivalent to adding that column to your data frame and then mapping it, outside `aes` tells ggplot "hey, just do this, but don't worry about adding it to the data frame or legends or anything".